# Llamar a una función que me devuelve un resultado numérico en Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

En el controlador tengo esta función:

```
public function total($id)
{
$expenses = new Expense();
$result = $expenses->where('budget_id', $id)->sum('amount');
$total = (int)$result;              

return $total;
}
```

La ruta la tengo generada:

```
Route::get('budget/mybudgets/{id}', 'BudgetController@total')->name('budget.total');
```

y en la vista estoy llamando a esta función:

```
<strong>{{ route('budget.total', ['id'=>$budget->id]) }} €</strong>
```

cuando visualizo la interfaz veo que me esta generando es una URL no me esta devolviendo el valor numérico, lo que me chirria es que si cojo la URL y la pego en el navegador me devuelve lo que quiero que es un resultado numérico.

[image: Resultado en la Vista]

[image: Resultado cuando pego la URL en el navegador]

Sabéis que estoy haciendo mal?

Un cordial saludo

Comment: normalmente yo siempre antes de mandar una variable a una vista utilizo `dd($variable)` para verificar que me devuelva lo que estoy intentando hacer, intenta hacer con `$total` para ver si realmente te lo esta convirtiendo a `int`.

Comment: Buenos días, si hice un var_dump de $total y me devuelve el valor que quiero como un int

Comment: probaste enviando la variable a la vista con `view` y no con `return` ?    `return view(home, [ 'total' => $total   ])` ?? sinceramente soy nuevo con laravel y aun existen cosas que no se como funciona pero aveces pruebo de todo y asi encuentro las diferencias..

Comment: gracias por el comentario pero no me funciona así porque es una función que quiero llamar desde la vista para me retorne un resultado

Comment: Y cuál se supone es el error?

Comment: Es que estás imprimiendo en tu vista la url generada para esa ruta. Si quieres obtener el valor que te devuelve la ruta/controlador para imprimirlo en la vista, tendrías que hacer una llamada ajax por ejemplo.

Comment: Que en vez de aparecerme **Prueba: 135**, me sale **Prueba: https://admin-account.com.devel/budget/mybudgets/52**